# Where does the magic column "name" come from?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.0

I got this by accident:

```
db=> select name from site;
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: select name from site;
               ^
db=> select site.name from site;
     name
---------------
 (1,mysitename)
(1 row)
```

The second query return a tuple containing a whole row. Using postgres 9.0.1.

Edit: the definition of site by request. I doesn't really matter, this quirk works for any table.

```
db=> \d site
                         Table "public.site"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('site_id_seq'::regclass)
 title  | text    | not null
```

Comment: It would help to show the definition of `site`.

Comment: ~ It _does_ matter because now we can see that there is no "name" in `site` to begin with. Why would you query for a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: Try `select site from site` - this will help you understand Gaius's answer in more detail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NAME` is actually a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xfunc-sql.html). It's a quirk of Postgres that a function with one argument e.g. `function(arg)` can also be called as `arg.function`. From the docs:

> The equivalence between functional
>   notation and attribute notation makes
>   it possible to use functions on
>   composite types to emulate "computed
>   fields".

`NAME` is an [internal type for object names](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE), and this function is casting its argument to that type and returning it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. What bothers me, if this particular function "name" is documented anywhere?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: More precisely, the `row` type is being cast to `text` because that is the input type of the function `name`. The `name` function is then converting (not casting) the input string to type `name` (which will also have the side effect of truncating to 64 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

Also note that the implicit cast to name was removed in PostgreSQL 8.3, which means this behavior no longer works.  It is virtually impossible to accidently get this behavior in PostgreSQL 8.3 and higher because tuples don't automatically convert to text.

So in 9.1:

```
or_examples=# select c.name from comp_table_test c;
ERROR:  column c.name does not exist
LINE 1: select c.name from comp_table_test c;
```

but to get that behavior we have to:

```
or_examples=# select name(c::text) from comp_table_test c;
```

Or we could define our own name function taking in type comp_table_test and returning whatever we'd like.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. You're saying the question posed above shouldn't be a problem anymore on 8.3 or higher? Yet the question asks about 9.0

Answer (score 0):

"name" is a [reserved key word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). So you should "quote" the keyword to use it:

```
SELECT "name" FROM site;
```

This has resolved some of these issues for me in the past, altough the code you posted should also work without quoting. On the other hand

```
select site.name from site;
```

word because you are explicitly using the schema to resolve the name of the column

Comment: A lot of reserved words can be used, and in this case it quoting doesn't help.  This is because if site.name does not exist as a column then, pre-8.3, what would happen is you'd start looking for name functions taking in a site data type *or* a type implicitly cast from site.  Since site could be implicitly cast to text, name(text) would be used.  Consequently `select site.name from site` might be implicitly transformed to `select name(site::text) from site` which is where the magic comes from.